Nodes, channels and capacity on LN
I have a question regarding Lightning Network on Bitcoin.
I am currently looking into it, but I need to gather some data.
What I would like in a table. Node, Capacity of the node, number of channels to the node.
Is it possible to obtain a csv file or a place to look up these data? I have tried to look into different explorers but I cannot really find all the data. If you have a good guide for setting up LN for a windows user, where I could find the data please also direct me.
I would like to get this data for all the nodes on LN like +13000 nodes.
Thanks in advance!
I have tried to look into different explorers like: https://amboss.space/ and https://terminal.lightning.engineering/
Amboss don't have a full list, but terminal does. The problem with terminal is they don't show all the nodes but only good peers.
